# Grafana is querying many null values from Graphite

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have set up Graphite and Grafana to run in docker. metrics are pushed to Graphite maybe a few times per day. I have set up graphs in Grafana to view these metrics from Graphite. Since there is few values once Grafana has queried a value it will get a null value the next query.

Is there a way to avoid this? Currently I'm using Transform -> filter data by values in Grafana to remove the null values. But is there a better way to avoid having tables full of mostly null values?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to configure the storage-schema.conf and storage-aggregation.conf in Graphite